# application_helper.rb not refreshing after restart server Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Rails app using i18n. It's fine until I try to modify the application_helper.rb there is a part that stands:

```
 def language_css(language)

    case language
      when 'en'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/en.css">'
      when 'es-MX'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/es.css">'
      when 'fr'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/fr.css">'
      when 'jp'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/jp.css">'
      when 'ch'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/ch.css">'
      when 'ar'
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/ar.css">'
      default
        return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/es.css">'
    end
  end
```

I tried to change default `"es.css"` for `"en.css"` but I see no changes. The `es.css` file is still the default css file, not `en.css`.

So I even tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and `rails s`, several times, no luck.

Comment: Can you verify whether those localized CSS files are actually in your assets folder, and that they indeed include the content that each is supposed to contain?

Comment: Yes they are, actually they work like charm.. i just need to change default lenguage, but actually the files are there, all is loading

Comment: How are you passing the `language` argument to your `language_css` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with reloading, your `case` statement is simply not doing what you think. `default` here is a method call, not a keyword. You’re looking for `else`. Properly indented, this becomes clear:

```
case language
when 'en'
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/en.css">'

# Skipping some cases because they’re not needed for the example

when 'ar'
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/ar.css">'
  default
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/es.css">'
end
```

As we can see, the second and third lines of the `when 'ar'` case are never reached, because it always returns. You instead want `else`:

```
case language
when 'en'
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/en.css">'

# Skipping some cases because they’re not needed for the example

when 'ar'
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/ar.css">'
else
  return raw '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/es.css">'
end
```

---

Your code can ultimately be written more simply as:

```
def language_css(language)
  css_file = {
    'en' => 'en.css',
    'es-MX' => 'es.css',
    'fr' => 'fr.css',
    'jp' => 'jp.css',
    'ch' => 'ch.css',
    'ar' => 'ar.css',
  }.fetch(language, 'es.css')

  raw %(<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/#{css_file}">)
end
```

Comment: Thanks really man!, the default is working perfect with en.css now, but i get this prints #{css_file}" like this, so no other lenguage is working, what am i missing to print (echo)  with the actual css

Comment: @MonchoChavez That’s because it needs to be a double-quoted string for the interpolation to work. Updated answer.

Comment: sorry im a real newbie on rails, the problem is somewhere else even with your code its inserting es.css, and the URL show nothing but domain, i guess, im setting es-Mx as default in other part of the code somthing of i18n , damn, in application.rb i have set this also : config.i18n.default_locale = 'en'. im so lost

Comment: Just fixed using this in the layout/views <%= language_css(params[:locale] || 'en') %> thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you just have a bug in your code you're missing. I'd rewrite your method entirely.

```
def language_css(language)
  asset = language.downcase

  return raw stylesheet_link_tag(asset) if Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{asset}.css").present?

  raw stylesheet_link_tag('es')
end
```

You'll need to rename `es.css` to `es-mx.css`.